# Как выделить запятыми словосочетания "может (,) лучше"; "может (,) и"?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Тогда, может, лучше пойдем в кино.
2. Может, лучше пойдем в кино.
3. А может, лучше в кино сходим ?
4. А может, и в кино сходим.

Comment: Меня интересует именно словосочетание "а может и" . Я не эксперт, поэтому не знаю, как точно сформулировать этот вопрос. Конкретного правила на данное словосочетание "а может и" я найти не могу. Могу только привести еще пару примеров:        Одну простую сказку, 
А может, и не сказку... (из м/ф "Пластилиновая ворона").                    "Люди, которыми я мог бы стать, а может, и стал"  (название фильма).

Answer (score 4):

Во всех ваших примерах "может" является вводным словом. Запятые в ваших примерах поставлены верно. Слово "может" не обособляется тогда, когда является членом предложения. Ср.: Он может сделать это( может - здесь член предложения, запятая не нужна).